# Place UIButton with dynamic tex at the center of UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, iphone, uibutton

I have a `UIButton` in table cell. I want to place the button at the center of the cell. The text of the button is dynamic. This is what I have tried, but it's not coming at the center. It is coming towards the right of center.

```
UIButton *btnName = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, MAXFLOAT);
NSStringDrawingOptions options = NSStringDrawingTruncatesLastVisibleLine |
NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin;

NSDictionary *attr = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15]};
CGRect labelBounds = [titleText boundingRectWithSize:maximumLabelSize
                                             options:options
                                          attributes:attr
                                             context:nil];
CGFloat width = ceilf(labelBounds.size.width);

btnName.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, imgPic.frame.origin.y+imgPic.frame.size.height+20.0, width, 20.0);
btnName.center = CGPointMake(cell.contentView.center.x, imgPic.frame.origin.y+imgPic.frame.size.height+10.0);

[btnName setTitle:titleText forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnName setTitleColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cell.contentView addSubview:btnName];
```

Comment: Have you tried `btnName.center = cell.contentView.center` ? You might also want to do the centering AFTER you set the title of the button.

Comment: @Zhang : Yes I tried this but not working.

Comment: @WorldOfWarcraft : Do I need to set center and frame as well. It would help if you can post your answer.

Comment: You want to place the button at the center of cell? or the cell's contentView? They are quite different.

Comment: @WorldOfWarcraft : At horizontal center.

Comment: set back color of your button to debug it, it will show where you make mistake.

Comment: Why not use Autolayout? I found [how to do it in visual format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12873372/centering-a-view-in-its-superview-using-visual-format-language).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Vladimir's**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908510/center-uibutton-programatically) answer saved my day. I used setAutoresizingMask and now it is coming absolutely fine.

Answer (score 2):

Just add below line in your code.

```
btnName.center = cell.center;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, only you've to make these change,

1. You should center the button after you add it cell, and
2. Correct the center points

---

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:btnName];

btnName.center = CGPointMake(cell.frame.size.width/2.f, btnName.center.y);
```