# Can't centre UITextField in UIView

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, uitextfield

I'm trying to add my `UITextField` to a `UIView` that is placed in the centre of the table. The `UIView` works fine and is positioned correctly. however the `UITextField` is in the wrong position and at the bottom left of the screen. Code below:

```
    self.addFriendView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 50)];
    self.addFriendView.center=self.view.center;
    [self.addFriendView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    UITextField *nameField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 280, 40)];
    nameField.delegate=self;
    nameField.center=self.view.center;
    nameField.placeholder=@"enter username";
    [self.addFriendView addSubview:nameField];
    [self.tableView.superview addSubview:self.addFriendView];
```

When I am placing the `UITextField` in the centre of the `UIView` do the coordinates need to be inside the `UIView`'s coordinates or the frames?

Comment: What method is this code in?

Comment: Perhaps a similar Stack Overflow question would be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908510/center-uibutton-programatically

Good luck

Answer (score 2):

That's because `addFriendView.center` is it's center in it's superview coordinate which is `{150, 25}`. What you want is that put the center of `nameField` in the center of `addFriendView` in `addFriendView`'s coordinate.

So, use this:

```
nameField.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(addFriendView.bounds), 
                               CGRectGetMidY(addFriendView.bounds));
```

Updated to use `CGRectGetMidX` and `CGRectGetMidY` instead.

Comment: More better is use CGRectGetMid* methods, them good for any rects: nameField.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(addFriendView.bounds),  CGRectGetMidY(addFriendView.bounds));

Answer (score 0):

Because you have added `nameField` as a subview of `self.addFriendView`, its center will need to be relative to `self.addFriendView`.

```
nameField.center=self.view.center;
```

This line here is causing your issue. If fact, it's also an issue where you assign `self.addFriendView`'s `center`, but by luck, `self.view`'s bounds happen to be the same as its superview's.

Instead, you'll want to do this:

```
nameField.center=CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.addFriendView.bounds),
                             CGRectGetMidY(self.addFriendView.bounds));
```

and also, just for robustness:

```
self.addFriendView.center=CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.view.bounds),
                                      CGRectGetMidY(self.view.bounds));
```